# Loop through set of files and check if it is comma delimited in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to loop through set of files  and check if it is comma delimited or not in C#.I am very new to C#.Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? How would you know whether a file is comma delimited or not? Is having one or more commas in the text enough?

Comment: Why not use one of the many CSV libraries available and see if the file validates?

Comment: You have SSIS tagged, are you attempting to use C# within SSIS? Must you use C# or is your root problem that you need to validate files within SSIS? Is there an expected format for a CSV (N columns) or will anything with commas suffice? Try updating your question with more detail else the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out it is not going to be easy solution.
It *could* be very easy if every comma delimited file had a specified extension (for example: csv). If not the following algorigthm should work:

1. Retrieve all names (paths + names) of files in specified directory. If needed filter only those that may be of interest. Hint: take a look at `System.IO.Directory` and `System.IO.File` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo`
2. You have to examine every file, and check if it is comma delimited or not. This is going to be tricky part. You could build a regular expression, that will check each line of the file and and tell you if it is comma delimited or not.

Regular expressions are a bit hard to learn at the beginning but it should pay back after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick Console app that will take a directory, scan the directory for all files, then iterate through them and return a percentage of lines containing commas -vs- the total lines in the file. As has been pointed out, there are CSV libraries you can validate against. This is just a quick example to get you started.

To use this, create a new Console App project in Visual Studio and name it "TestStub" then copy and past this into the "Program.cs" file.

```
namespace TestStub
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;

    public class Program
    {
        private static char[] CSV = { ',', ',' };
        private static bool csvFound = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the console program entry point
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">A list of any command-line args passed to this application when started</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Change this to use args[0] if you like 
            string myInitialPath = @"C:\Temp";
            string[] myListOfFiles;

            try
            {
                myListOfFiles = EnumerateFiles(myInitialPath);

                foreach (string file in myListOfFiles)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nFile {0} is comprised of {1}% CSV delimited lines.",
                        file, 
                        ScanForCSV(file));
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Error processing {0} for CSV content: {1} :: {2}", 
                    myInitialPath, 
                    ex.Message, 
                    ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a list of all files for the specified path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">Directory path</param>
        /// <returns>String array of files (with full path)</returns>
        public static string[] EnumerateFiles(string path)
        {
            string[] arrItems = new string[1];

            try
            {
                arrItems = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                return arrItems;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new System.IO.IOException("EnumerateFilesAndFolders() encountered an error:", ex);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the supplied file has comma separated values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">Path and filename</param>
        /// <returns>Percentage of lines containing CSV elements -vs- those without</returns>
        public static float ScanForCSV(string filename)
        {
            //
            // NOTE: You should look into one of the many CSV libraries
            // available. This method will not carefully scruitinize
            // the file to see if there's a combination of delimeters or
            // even if it's a plain-text (e.g. a newspaper article)
            // It just looks for the presence of commas on multiple lines
            // and calculates a percentage of them with and without
            //
            float totalLines = 0;
            float linesCSV = 0;

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    int elements = 0;
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    string[] parsed = new string[1];

                    while (!sReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        ++totalLines;
                        line = sReader.ReadLine();
                        parsed = line.Split(CSV);
                        elements = parsed.Length;
                        if (elements > 1)
                        {
                            ++linesCSV;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new System.IO.IOException(string.Format("Problem accessing [{0}]: {1}", filename, ex.Message), ex);
            }
            return (float)((linesCSV / totalLines) * 100);
        }
    }  
}
```

}