# How to Ignore Wrong Delimited Notepad Files in SSIS and continue Package

Tags: ssis

I am taking SOURCE from Comma Delimiter Notepad files in a SSIS Package.

However, sometimes..Some TAB delimited files also come by mistake. How can I ignore such files and continue reading rest of the correct delimited files and continue the package?

Answer (score 0):

The two options I can think of are:

1. After reading the files from the Source, add a **Foreach Container**, and within the "Enumerator configuration" section add a "*.csv" filter. This will filter out any files that are not comma-separated and have a .csv extension.

   Example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

   This will only work if your comma delimited and tab delimited files have different extensions though.
2. You can add a **Script Task** within your data flow task, which will open each file and determine the delimiter. You can then ignore the tab delimited files. The drawback of this approach is that you need to open each file to check them.

   Example: [Loop through set of files and check if it is comma delimited in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955258/loop-through-set-of-files-and-check-if-it-is-comma-delimited-in-c-sharp)

Hope this helps.